# Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 and Exchange Transport Role - Licensing

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Do I need a separate Windows Server 2008 R2 licence just to run the Edge Transport Role?

It seems a bit silly that I have to purchase another full windows server licence just to run the Edge role.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Windows license for each Windows server. The Edge Transport role is not required, but if you choose to utilize it, you need to license the server that it runs on.